# Aura : Input Select , Drop Down

Tags: apex, community, lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

**Component Code:**

```xml
<aura:component controller="TestController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">   
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <aura:attribute name="country" type="Contact" default="{ sobjectType: 'Contact' }" />


  <ui:inputSelect label = "country" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.country.Country__c}" var="CountryName">
           <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!CountryName}" label="{!CountryName}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
          
  </ui:inputSelect> 
</aura:compomnent>
```

**Controller Code**

```javascript
({
  doInit: function(component, evt, helper) {
    
    var action = component.get("c.getAccount");
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
     component.set("v.country", a.getReturnValue());
     
    });
      
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
  },
  


})
```

**Apex Controller**

```
public class TestController{ 
  @AuraEnabled 
  public static Account getAccount() {
    return [select Country__c from Contact]; 
  }
}
```

Question :
I am not getting any record in the drop down , can any one tell me what is wrong with the code.
my controller is having simple SQL select query and that is working fine.

Comment: post your "TestController" apex class too please. Also you iterate on contact list, I see that you are iterating on country of the contact(assuming it is a string, you would get an error)

Comment: I'd suggest posting the Apex code as well. It is conceivable that something is going wrong there. Finally, are you getting any errors in the developer tools? Have you checked the profile of the community user has access to the Apex class, and to Contact?

Comment: well spotted @Rao I suspect it is iterating on the field instead of the attribute that is the problem. You should post an answer.

Comment: @AuraEnabled    public static Account getAccount() {         return [select LastName__c from Account ];    }}

Comment: <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"  default="{ sobjectType: 'Account' }"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <force:inputField  value="{!v.account.LastName__c}" />
    
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ui:inputSelect label = "country" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic">
     <aura:iteration items="{!v.account.LastName__c}" var="Name">
               <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!Name}" label="{!Name}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </ui:inputSelect>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just display picklist `country__c` related to the contact on the UI

**Approach 1 using `force:inputfield`**

**Component:**

```xml
<aura:component controller="testconaura">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="contact"  type="Contact" default="{ sobjectType: 'Contact' }" />
    <force:inputField value="{!v.contact.LeadSource}">
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```javascript
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getcontact");
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
     component.set("v.contact", a.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
  }
})
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public class testconaura {
  @AuraEnabled 
  public static contact getcontact() {
    return [select id,name,LeadSource from Contact limit 1]; 
  }
}
```

**Renderer:**

There is a bug with picklist when using `force:inputField` for which a workaround is provided here

[Lightning Components: why force:inputField picklist select renders disabled?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/97046/lightning-forceinputfield-picklist-select-disabled)

```javascript
({
    render : function(cmp, helper) {
    var element = this.superRender();
    element[0].children[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
    return element;
}
})
```

**Approach 2: populating pick list values dynamically through apex controller:**

**COPY PASTE THE EXACT CODE AND CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINE IN THE APEX CLASS TO GET THE DESIRED PICKLIST**

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = contact.Leadsource.getDescribe();
```

**Component:**

```xml
<aura:component controller="dcontroller">
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" /> 
    <ui:inputSelect label="Lead source pickval: " class="dynamic" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic"/>
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller:**

```javascript
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getpickval");
        var inputsel = component.find("InputSelectDynamic");
        var opts=[];
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
            for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++){
                opts.push({"class": "optionClass", label: a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]});
            }
            inputsel.set("v.options", opts);

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        }
})
```

**Apex class:**

```
public class dcontroller {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<String> getpickval() {
        List<String> options = new List<String>();
    
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = contact.Leadsource.getDescribe();
    
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: ple) {
            options.add(f.getLabel());
        }       
        return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rao , in the <aura:iteration items="{!v.country} if i use v.country - i get failed to initialize component JS error
So i used items = !v.CountryName.Country__c

Comment: i changed the code to iterate name field having multiple records - but drop down is blank - posted the component code and controller code above

Comment: @nikx is country__c a picklist? are you trying to just put the country picklist related to the contact on the UI?

Comment: I am ok with either of it -
1. I tried with picklist in input field but facing issue with making it enable as by default it is disabled
2. Then I tried with inputselect - where I am fetching account records and trying to populate dynamically.

I am looking for a drop down code in lightning component which can be generated dynamically using controller

Comment: My original code was based on country__c as a picklist - but that would not work in inputselect.

So i changed it to fetching records and populating in inputselect.

If you have code for generating dropdown dynamically you can share.

Comment: I have put the render code in JS file - 
but it is not getting  triggered- Can you tell me if I need to add anything else.

Comment: you need to click on renrender (rerender is not JS controller) rerender is a component of lightning that helps renrender components after loading DOM elements

Comment: I clicked renderer and put the code in that file , 
I have put alert in that code , but it not triggering - and so dropdown is still disabled.
Thanks for the updates so far.

Comment: look at the alternate approach that i posted to the answer,

Comment: Approach 2 is working fine.

Comment: Will Approach 2 also respect translations? Not sure if describe is respecting Translation Workbench or return master-labels only... I fixed it with jQuery http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64580/lightning-how-to-use-forceinputfield/96645#96645

Comment: @UweHeim I have not worked with translation workbench, but reading this answer getlabel seems to return translated values (I have not tested this)  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10172/describe-use-picklist-values-in-specific-language-not-the-users-language